# How to return a File and then do the redirection in mvc, c# , .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

what I want is **when user click on a button in the view**, should **download** an `xml file` and then should **return** to the the **same view**.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model) {

  return RedirectToAction(nameof(getFile));
}
```

I defined a new `IActionResult` and then **returned** a File like below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getFile()
        {
   byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("myfile.xml");
   string filename = "myfile.xml";

   return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
}
```

This download a file to the browser , but cannot do the redirection. is this possible. if this is not the correct way, then how can I do it using .net core 2.0. hope your help with this.

Comment: How are you calling the controller initially? Is it possible to handle the redirect after your client side receives a response?

Comment: isn't it possible to do this only from server side(from the controller). I'm calling to the controller with user login

Comment: If that's a constraint for you then you should call it out in your question

Comment: If Content-disposition: attachment; header is set (and it should be in your case)  - most browser will just download file ans stay on the same page, so redirection should not be necessary.

Comment: @EVk how can I do that with my case

Answer (score 0):

You cannot turn one request (from requesting the `Login` action) into two for obvious reasons.

Instead one solution (I don't have enough context to give more specific details) would be to have the Redirect go to your desired redirected page (so just ignore downloading the file), then have that page load, and have some Javascript in the page that then sends an Ajax call or a Form click to do a file download.

There are many ways to do that download and it also depends if you want it to popup a **Save As** dialog or open inside the browser window (which I doubt as it would defeat the point of doing a download and redirect in your question).

Presuming you want to download a file after the page loads and via Javascript I would dynamically create and inject a  and set its action to another MVC Action URL (like your GetFile action) and then do a form.submit() in Javascript to simulate redirecting and then having the file popup.